# Replace XML attributes value with random number in shell script

Tags: linux, unix

Need to replace the RC value with random number in shell script
my test.xml file contain below XML snippet

<doc:meta title = 'test-title'></doc:meta><doc:meta title = 'test-title-2'></doc:meta>

Expected Ouput

<doc:meta title = 'test-title'></doc:meta><doc:meta title = 'test-title-2'></doc:meta>

Actual Results:
<doc:meta title = 'test-title'></doc:meta>

I have tried this but it is not working

```
var2=$RANDOM 
sed -i "s/^<item name="RC" .*/<item value=\"$var2\">/g;" test.xml
```

Comment: Double quotes don't nest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the embedded quotes:

```
sed "/<item name=\"RC\"/s/value=[^>]+/name=\"$var2\">/"
```

Comment: Thank tink, I have tried this it is giving below output
<item name="24374" i should get below output <item name="RC" value="random_number" </item> value should be some random number

Comment: My test.xml file contains  below XML snippets.                                     <doc-transform> <item name="RC" value="1445352777130287"></item> <item name="RC" value="14453287"></item> <item name="RC" value="3527771302"></item> </doc-transform>

Comment: @KAS  -  I added a new example ... you may want to put sample input and expected output into your question next time,

Answer (score 0):

You can use extended regex :

```
var2=$RANDOM 
sed -E -i 's|^(<item name="RC" value=").*("></item>)|\1'$var2'\2|' test.xml
```

Comment: I used the above regex for below Test.xml and observed that other XML getting trimmed can you please help me in understanding and correction?
Test.xml   <doc-transform> <item name="RC" value="1445352777130287"></item> <item name="RC" value="14453287"></item> <item name="RC" value="3527771302"></item> <item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item> <item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></dth-item> </doc-transform>  Output: <doc-transform> <item name="RC" value="2777130"></item> <item name="RC" value="14453900"></item> <item name="RC" value="898999"></item> </doc-transform>

Comment: In my test, the script still works with your xml in the comment. Can you paste you complete input xml and expected output in your question ? Do you want to update ONLY 1445352777130287 ?

Comment: Hi Philippe, I have updated the Question with test.xml,Actual Results and Expected results hope that helps you thank you for your response

Comment: Your xml has `doc:meta` tag, but your script processes `item` tag.

Comment: Not able to paste complete test.xml I will paste on comment one by one

Comment: Test.zml <documents><document id ="test"><doc:meta title = 'test-title'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="1445352"></item><item name="RC" value="14453287"></item></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></dth-item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document><document id ="test-2"><doc:meta title = 'test-title-2'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="090090"></item><item name="RC" value="008889"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></dth-item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document></documents>

Comment: Expected, documents><document id ="test"><doc:meta title = 'test-title'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="28468"></item><item name="RC" value="28468"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></dth-item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document><document id ="test-2"><doc:meta title = 'test-title-2'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="28468"></item><item name="RC" value="28468"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></dth-item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document></documents>

Comment: Actual Results, <documents><document id ="test"><doc:meta title = 'test-title'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="28468"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></dth-item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document></documents>